# Вызов асинхронной функции внутри асинхронной функции

Tags: javascript, node.js, async-await, асинхронность

Написал такую функцию, сделав её асинхронной:

```
const log = async function (text) {
    const withTime = now() + text;
    console.log(withTime);
    fs.appendFileSync(logFileName, withTime + '\n', function (){});
};
```

Исполнение функции `now()` может быть медленным. Также медленна запись в файл. Поэтому саму функцию log сделал асинхронной. Вопрос, нужно ли делать вызов `appendFile` асинхронным, или лучше вызывать синхронно? Или это не имеет значения?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

То, что вы сделали функцию асинхронной, не значит, что она стала параллельной. Она всё так же выполняется в том же одном потоке, просто завершится не сразу, а в конце очереди задач.

Соответственно она всё так же тормозит процесс, и смысла от её асинхронности нет.

Чтобы смысл был, нужно каждую тяжёлую функцию внутри сделать параллельной. Не все асинхронные функции параллельные. `fs.appendFile` или `fs.promises.appendFile` выполняются параллельно в другом потоке, так что стоит использовать их.

И `now()` возможно стоит вынести в отдельный поток, если она тяжёлая.

Есть ещё вариант тяжёлые функции дробить на мелкие асинхронные циклы, чтобы между сплошным выполнением были разрывы, в которых смогут выполниться другие задачи, и тем самым можно избежать длительного зависания.

Comment: Тогда вообще в чём смысл асинхронных функций? Я думал что если я с основной программы вызову log(), программа не остановится, а будет выполняться дальше. А функция log() будет выполняться параллельно. И, кстати, что будет, если не дождавшись завершения log(), вызвать его ещё раз? То что вы написали про то, что внутренность функции log() будет выполняться последовательно, это я понимаю. И то что now() стоит запараллелить тоже.

Comment: Смысл в асинхронности, что не то же самое, что параллельность. `setTimeout` например асинхронный, и ему не нужна параллельность. И например для слушателей событий мышки на странице тоже не нужна параллельность, но нужна асинхронность. Функции со словом async - это синтаксический сахар для более удобного использования вместо колбэков. Можете думать о них просто как об отложенном завершении или как о разрывающих сплошной поток выполнения. Но параллельности там никакой нет.

Comment: "что будет, если не дождавшись завершения log(), вызвать его ещё раз?" --- не получится его так вызвать ещё раз. Сначала выполнится первый в любом случае, потому что он стартует раньше и внутри только синхронные функции.